# Custom injection with standard annotations

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Is it possible to perform custom injection with constructor/factory arguments computed based on injection point WITHOUT defining custom annotation ?

Given a code:

```
class Foo {
  public Foo() {}
  public Foo(java.lang.reflect.Field field) {}
}

class Bar {
  @javax.inject.Inject Foo foo;
}
```

How can I configure guice to use second constructor of `Foo` (**passing target field**) without modifying `Bar`.

I know that guice can do custom injections of java.util.logging.Logger with standard @Inject but that seems hardcoded and uses internal api.

Answer (score 1):

You can use injection providers to do it. See https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProviderBindings and https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods. You just have to tell Guice how to instantiate the object when it binds it.

For exemple in a project of mine I tried this :

```
public static class CalendarServiceProvider implements Provider<CalendarService> {
    @Inject
    GAppsOAuth oauth;
    private GCalendarService service;

    @Override
    public CalendarService get() {
        if (service == null) {
            service = new GCalendarService(oauth);
        }
        return service;
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's what you're looking for, but I hope it'll help.

Comment: As mentioned in my question (in bold letters even), I need target field (i.e. injection context).

Answer (score -1):

If you want only to use specific constructor, you can use [constructor bindings](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ToConstructorBindings):

```
bind(Foo.class).toConstructor(Foo.class.getConstructor(java.lang.reflect.Field.class));
```

If you need something more complex, you have to use [custom injections](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomInjections).

Comment: I want "target field" and yes this is a custom injection. My question was how to do it without custom annotation.

Comment: @MarcinWisnicki, that is not very clear from your question what you want to do. If you just want to create `Foo` specifying its parameter manually but still allowing `Foo` to participate in dependency injection, you will have to use [providers](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProviderBindings), which are intended exactly for that. If you have even more complex scenario (when some of the parameters must be specified manually and some - injected by Guice), then you can use [assisted inject](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject).

Comment: @MarcinWisnicki, it seems that I understand what you need. You need to inject target field into the object being injected in this field, right? This really should be done via custom injection, but I believe that you cannot do it without custom annotations because `@Inject` is handled very specially by Guice. As you have already noticed, `j.u.l.Logger` injection is hardcoded in Guice core, it is an exception.